# Identity authentication over smb for Azure file share

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-storage-files

I have mounted an azure file share on an azure VM using access keys ,the VM is not doman joined with the azure active directory instance.Please let me know if below scenario's will work out:-

- If i apply acl's on the folders and sub folders will the acl's be
  enforced in the mounted drive  on the VM?
- Will AZURE RBAC apply if someone tries to upload a file from the VM?

Note:- The Azure VM is on a VNET which has access to azure active directory.
Any information/answer/suggestion on the above questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ACLs can exist for domain or non-domain accounts. Having a machine that is not domain joined, can obviously not set domain ACLs. So in that case local-server ACLs is all you can hope to get.
   If another server mounts the share, and there is not another local user account + SID mapping, then there is no way these ACLs have any meaning on the second machine. **But they will be enforced.**
   So that one will work albeit questionable in terms of usefulness.

   2. RBAC is really a management plane construct. Meant to govern who can manage which Azure resource --> not access which data planes. Now in the case of AD / AAD DS support for Azure file shares, the team has decided to "stretch" the meaning of RBAC to govern share-level ACLs via Kerberos (where normal RBAC is OAuth only!)
      Enough of the backend: What this basically means, is that there can be no support for local server accounts.
      THese accounts only exist on a local server, not in AAD and certainly not DIRSYNC'ed from on-prem AD into AAD. So that means RBAC cannot work for local accounts, only for domain accounts.
   3. I'm unclear what your scenario is.

- A user coming into the server with some sort of local user credential?
  Then creating/copying a file into a mounted Azure file share to that VM? --> That can work because there is no RBAC and since this is all happening through that single server that has that local user account, ACLs for these local accounts work natively.
- A user coming into the server with a domain cred? --> will not work as the server isn't domain joined.
- A user coming in with a local-server account and then using the Azure file share not via SMB mount but by going to the Azur file share directly: Cannot work because it's not a domain account and non-dimain accounts cannot work against Azure file shares. You'd use the srtorage access key to mount the file share to the VM, then you have access and leave auth. to the server with the set of local accounts.

Before you enable **Azure AD over SMB for Azure file shares**, make sure you have completed the following **prerequisites**:

Select or create an Azure AD tenant.

You can use a new or existing tenant for Azure AD authentication over SMB. The tenant and the file share that you want to access must be associated with the same subscription.

To create a new Azure AD tenant, you can Add an Azure AD tenant and an Azure AD subscription. If you have an existing Azure AD tenant but want to create a new tenant for use with Azure file shares, see [Create an Azure Active Directory tenant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/add-an-azure-ad-tenant-and-azure-ad-subscription)

Enable Azure AD Domain Services on the Azure AD tenant.

To support authentication with Azure AD credentials, you must enable Azure AD Domain Services for your Azure AD tenant. If you aren't the administrator of the Azure AD tenant, contact the administrator and follow the step-by-step guidance to [Enable Azure Active Directory Domain Services using the Azure portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance)

It typically takes about 15 minutes for an Azure AD DS deployment to complete. Verify that the health status of Azure AD DS shows Running, with password hash synchronization enabled, before proceeding to the next step.

Domain-join an Azure VM with Azure AD DS.

To access a file share by using Azure AD credentials from a VM, your VM must be domain-joined to Azure AD DS. For more information about how to domain-join a VM, see Join a [Windows Server virtual machine to a managed domain.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable)

**Note**:Azure AD DS authentication over SMB with Azure file shares is supported only on Azure VMs running on OS versions above Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

Select or create an Azure file share.

Select a new or existing file share that's associated with the same subscription as your Azure AD tenant. For information about [creating a new file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share?tabs=azure-portal), see Create a file share in Azure Files. For optimal performance, we recommend that your file share be in the same region as the VM from which you plan to access the share.

Verify Azure Files connectivity by mounting Azure file shares using your storage account key.

To verify that your VM and file share are properly configured, try mounting the file share using your storage account key. For more information, see [Mount an Azure file share and access the share in Windows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows)

Comment: The answer is really helpful .All the users who will be logging into the VM  will be using the azure AD credentials there are no local accounts involved.So if we have not created an azure ad domain service and my VM is not domain joined with the AAD tenant then azure ad authentication over SMB for a file share will not work and additionally if we are  applying ACL's to folders and sub folders by mounting the share those will also not be enforced ? i hope i have got the brief summary of your answer right , please let me know if you need any clarification from my end.